# Spark SQL push down query issue with max function in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I want to execute an aggregate function MAX on a table's ID column residing in MS SQL. I am using spark SQL 1.6 and JDBC push down_query approach as I don't want spark SQL to pull all the data on spark side and do `MAX (ID)` calculation, but when I execute below code I get below exception, whereas If I try `SELECT * FROM` in code it works as expected.

**Code:**

```
  def getMaxID(sqlContext: SQLContext,tableName:String) =
    {
      val pushdown_query = s"(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ${tableName}) as t"
      val maxID = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url = getJdbcProp(sqlContext.sparkContext).toString, table = pushdown_query, properties = getDBConnectionProperties(sqlContext.sparkContext))
                   .head().getLong(0)
      maxID
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is not related to Spark. You have to provide an alias for the column

```
val pushdown_query = s"(SELECT MAX(ID) AS max_id FROM ${tableName}) as t"
```

Comment: Yes it is working now after an alias for the column, but the same query without alias is working with MS SQL, hence I thought it was not required in spark sql ,; Anyways, thanks a lot for the answer.